# Linux delete lines from ini-file where key has no value

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed

I have a config file with different values formatted like this:

```
[Global]

control_ip =
control_port =
control_socket = /run/tipper.sock
control_pass =
```

Now I just want to delete the lines that have no value after `=`, of course without deleting the `[Global]` section header.

Comment: If there's line end after `=`,  `sed '/=$/d' file` should work.

Comment: Seems to have no effect so far, have you tried it yourself?

Comment: Yes. You might have whitespaces after `=` and I clearly mentioned in my comment, *"If there's line end after `=`...."*. You can verify the same with `cat -e file`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed '/=\s*$/d' infile
```

or

```
sed '/=[[:blank:]]*$/d' infile
```

delete those lines that ends with `=` followed by zero-or-more whitespaces.

---

Using `awk` and preserve the empty lines:

```
awk -F'[=\t ]' '$NF!="" || /^$/' infile
```

or

```
awk -F'=[[:blank:]]*' '$NF!="" || /^$/' infile
```